# Draw random element from small intersection of two large lists fast

Tags: performance, hashset

I have two large lists for example with 10^7 and 10^5 elements. Their intersection is expected to contain, let's say 10^3 elements. I do not need the intersection set itself, but only one random element of it. I have to do this often, each time for new sets, so performance very important.

The sets contain integers. They are sparse and unevenly populated with different distributions. I would know the maximum value (typically 10^9) or other "normal" statitcal properties for free. (Also hashsets of those lists could be given for free)

I want to draw the common element from both list uniformly distributed. (each of the 10^3 with same chance).

Is there a fast way to do it? Faster than calculating the intersection and faster then drawing randomly from one and checking if contained in other.

Comment: Sort both lists, then follow the logic for merging two sorted lists, it'll give you the smallest entry that appears in both.

Comment: @MarkLavin thank you for commenting. The two list can come sorted for free. However i do need a uniformly chosen random element, not the smallest one. Any further idea would be appreciated. I thinking around the idea of doing your point with a scrambled version of the lists, don't i don't quite get it done.

Comment: Then (as both lists are sorted) just start not from the smallest element, but from random position

Comment: Here the problem would be the the lists are to unevenly filled. It would choose the element "after a gap" much more often.